# `npm run gulp` can not find module 'gulp-shell'?

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line, gulp, gulp-shell

I've deleted `node modules` folder and installed npm using `npm install` command. My `gulpfile.js` is also perfect because other people are working perfectly with this config, even I did with this config from my another machine. But when I try to run `npm run gulp` from current machine it shows below errors.

```
Fahads-MacBook-Pro:dark-web jim$ npm run gulp

> jetaport@1.0.0 gulp /Users/jim/Documents/JETAPORT/dark-web
> gulp

module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-shell'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jim/Documents/JETAPORT/dark-web/gulpfile.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! jetaport@1.0.0 gulp: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jetaport@1.0.0 gulp script 'gulp'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the jetaport package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs jetaport
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jetaport
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jim/Documents/JETAPORT/dark-web/npm-debug.log
```

And here is the `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "jetaport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The Jetaport Gulp dependencies.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Alexander Khost",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/akhost/Jetaport.git"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "bower": "^1.7.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.0.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "pixrem": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-conditionals": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-each": "^0.9.1",
    "postcss-import": "^7.1.3",
    "postcss-math": "0.0.1",
    "postcss-mixins": "^4.0.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.3",
    "postcss-simple-extend": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^1.1.0",
    "precss": "^1.3.0",
    "yargs": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akhost/Jetaport/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/akhost/Jetaport#readme",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "devDependencnpm ies": {
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "bower": "bower"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your package.json

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I've added that. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `package.json` is missing the `gulp-shell` package. You have to install it with `npm install --save gulp-shell` (or `--save-dev` if you want to put it under `devDependencies`). Not sure how others got it working, but I'm pretty confident they have installed it themselves, similarly to what I've suggested, without the save flag, which is the reason it's missing in `package.json`.

Comment: Awesome. `gulp-shell` was missing. I've installed with `npm install --save-dev gulp-shell` . The reason behind it is I forgot to pull down the latest update of the package from upstream. Thanks man!